# Placing a JLabel at a specific x,y coordinate on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jcomponent, null-layout-manager

I'm trying to place a series of JLabels at specific X and Y coordinates on a JPanel (and set its height and width, too). No matter what I do, each label winds up immediately to the right of the previous label and has the exact same size as all of the others.

Right now, my Jpanel is in a Grid Layout. I've tried Absolute Layout (illegal argument exception results), Free Design (no labels appear), Flow Layout (everything just gets squeezed to the center), and a few others.

Not sure what I need to do to make this work. Can anyone help?  Thanks!

```
JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("label 1");
JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("label 2");
JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("label 3");
JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel("label 4");
JLabel lbl5 = new JLabel("label 5");

myPanel.add(lbl1);
myPanel.add(lbl2);
myPanel.add(lbl3);
myPanel.add(lbl4);
myPanel.add(lbl5);

lbl1.setLocation(27, 20);
lbl2.setLocation(123, 20);
lbl3.setLocation(273, 20);
lbl4.setLocation(363, 20);
lbl5.setLocation(453, 20);

lbl1.setSize(86, 14);
lbl2.setSize(140, 14);
lbl3.setSize(80, 14);
lbl4.setSize(80, 14);
lbl5.setSize(130, 14);
```

Comment: You have to set your container's Layout to null

`myPanel.setLayout(null);`

Comment: Ack! That was about the only layout that I didn't try. Thanks! If you enter this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: *"I'm trying to place a series of JLabels at specific X and Y coordinates on a JPanel"*  Why?

Comment: most probably you do _not_ want to manually size/locate all children of a container - that's the exclusive task of a LayoutManager. So your task it to learn different behaviour of their respective implementations and choose one that fits your requirement

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to set your container's Layout to null:

```
myPanel.setLayout(null);
```

However is a good advise also to take a look at the Matisse Layout Manager, I guess it is called GroupLayout now. The main problem with absolute positioning is what happens when the window changes its size.

Comment: *"main problem .. window changes its size."* So that must leave the minor problems as:  Figuring the logic for the size of a component using different fonts, PLAFs, screen settings.. or accommodating other groups of components.  Using a `null` layout is most often a ***very*** bad idea.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes I agree that using a null layout is a bad idea generally. However consider applications that have a fixed window size or some of them running in embedded devices that runs that single application. In that cases, probably arranging the components with a layout could be just extra work and memory. Regards

Comment: *"probably arranging the components with a layout could be just extra work"* Until the point the client looks at the UI, frowns in concentration, and says,  "Move the 'OK' button from below to above the check boxes".

Comment: @AndrewThompson, probably that is a different problem or the result of doing poor analysis or design process, But this is going away of the real question: **"Placing a JLabel at a specific x,y coordinate on a JPanel"**. I don't have all the contextual information that questioner has to criticize the way he is doing things or why he is doing that way.

Comment: *"I don't have all the contextual information"*  So if someone ask you "How do I shoot myself in the foot?", lacking further contextual information, provide instructions?  Sometimes it is better to challenge the need for a question or strategy, than to immediately provide an answer that is almost certain to cause further problems.  OTOH, you seem to hold a different view..

Comment: @AndrewThompson no, I share your point of view about challenging people. If you read again the answer, I did it after provide it,  pointing out the main problem with the strategy provided but knowing that there is a real question that need an answer. But if you think you are right so you are right, I think it is not worth to start a long debate for something as short as this. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

1. Set the container's layout manager to null by calling `setLayout(null)`.
2. Call the Component class's `setbounds` method for each of the container's children.
3. Call the Component class's repaint method.

Note:

Creating containers with absolutely positioned containers can cause problems if the window containing the container is resized.

Refer this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Answer (score 3):

Layout managers are used to automatically determine the layout of components in a container. If you want to put components at specific coordinate locations, then you should not use a layout manager at all.

```
myPanel = new JPanel(null);
```

*or*

```
myPanel.setLayout(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

My advise is to use an IDE like [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) with its GUI editor. To inspect the code and because there are many ways:

Setting the layout manager, or for absolute positioning doing a myPanel.setLayout(null), has several influences.

In general, assuming you do your calls in the constructor of a JFrame, you can call `pack()` to start the layouting.

Then, every layout manager uses its own implementation of `add(Component)` or `add(Component, Constraint)`. BorderLayout's usage is with add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Best solution!!

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("aaa");
    panel.add(label);
    Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
    label.setBounds(100, 100, size.width, size.height);

    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own method that calling by setSize, setLocation values for directly....! `
As well i show you how to use JProgress Bar

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class installComp{
    void install(Component comp, int w, int h, int x, int y){
        comp.setSize(w,h);
        comp.setLocation(x,y);
    }
}
class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    int cur_val = 0;
    JButton btn = new JButton("Mouse Over");
    JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar(0,100);
    MyFrame (){
        installComp comp=new installComp();

        comp.install(btn,150,30,175,20);
        comp.install(progress,400,20,50,70);

        btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt){
                cur_val+=2;
                progress.setValue(cur_val);
                progress.setStringPainted(true);
                progress.setString(null);
            }
        }); 
        add(btn);
        add(progress);
        setLayout(null);    
        setSize(500,150); 
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyFrame f1=new MyFrame();   
    }
}
```

Comment: manual positioning/sizing (== not using a LayoutManager) always was, is, and will be wrong ...