# JLabel text position

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I´m new with `JLabel`, i wonder if it's possible to set the text in a coordenate specific (x,y) over an image.

**Like this:**

[image]

So the text is "HI"

```
 label.setText("HI");
 label.setIcon(icon);
```

I'm trying to say that `label` contains an image and  a text but i want to locate it in a specific position like the image above.

I don't want to use `label.setHorizontalTextPosition(i);`
or `setVerticalTextPosition(i);`

Sorry for my bad english
Thanks in advance ^ ^

Comment: Is this what you looking for? `label.setBounds(x, y, width, height);`

Comment: no, i want to locate the text of an JLabel that contains an image at specific position. I don't speak english very well so it's difficult to explain me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing a JLabel at a specific x,y coordinate on a JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119327/placing-a-jlabel-at-a-specific-x-y-coordinate-on-a-jpanel)

Comment: Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By overriding the `paintComponent` method, text can be drawn in any position.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon) {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Hi", 10, 10); //these are x and y positions
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly i want

Answer (score 3):

There are any number of, reasonable, ways to do it.

However, you should avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

## `GridBagLayout` and `GridBagConstraints#insets`

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
            JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
            background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 46, 9, 0);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
            gbc.weighty = 1;

            JLabel message = new JLabel("Go that way!");
            message.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
            background.add(message, gbc);

            add(background);
        }

    }

}
```

## `Graphics2D`

You could paint the text directly onto the image, but as you can see, it becomes considerably more complex

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            JLabel background = new JLabel();

            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setFont(background.getFont());
            String text = "Go that way!";
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

            int x = 46 + (((img.getWidth() - 46) - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2);
            int y = (((img.getHeight() - fm.getHeight())) + fm.getAscent()) - 9;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();

            background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            add(background);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/Layout/Set_location_of_JLabel_in_a_JFrame.htm), also take a look on [`setLocation()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation-int-int-) method for `Components` like `JLabel`, also try to use `Layouts` to manage better the position for each `Component`.

This [guy](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/302338/adding-a-label-at-specifc-location) also work with location with `JLabel`, you can see how he does the work and apply it in your project.

### Example

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hi");
panel.add(label);
//This is to get the width and height
Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
//You can change 100(x) and 100(y) for your likes, so you can put that JLabel wherever you want
label.setBounds(100, 100, size.width, size.height);
```

You'll have to know what `x` and what `y` you want to put the `JLabel` right there.

If you want to do that, just do what [`tong1`](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/302338/adding-a-label-at-specifc-location#post1298157) did, but showing the `x` and `y` to know where exactly you want it.

Create a `Container`

```
Container container= getContentPane();
```

Add the `JLabel` on it

```
container.add(label);
```

Add an `MouseListener()` to get the `x` and `y`

```
container.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ 
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        //x and y are ints.
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            label.setBounds(x,y,150,50);
        }
    });
```

Comment: [*"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @MadProgrammer updated, that is clear or shall I put more information?

Comment: But, there is not a way to do it in the same JLabel (the image and text)?